# How do I embed an uploaded binary files (ASCII-8BIT) in an XML (UTF-8)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a file which is uploaded via a regular `form_for`, this gives me a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object in the params hash on which I can call `.read` to get the content. I now need to embed the file in an XML document. I'm using a regular Ruby string for now to construct the XML. The default encoding for a Rails string is utf-8.

Therefore I get the error `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError`, `"\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`.

This happens for the following files:

```
what-matters-now-1.pdf: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
example.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8
investigations.png: image/png; charset=binary
```

It does not happen for:

```
my_test.txt: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

I have tried changing the encoding, but I get the same error:

```
params[:file].read.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot embed a binary file in an XML document without some sort of conversion to text. At least the PDF document and the PNG image need to be encoded somehow - probably [`Base64`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html) - before you start trying to treat their contents as strings of characters instead of sequences of bytes.

The `UndefinedConversionError` indicates that you're trying to convert text into UTF-8 from what Ruby thinks is ASCII. But the source text includes a byte whose value is 0x89 (137 decimal), which is outside the ASCII range. That is not at all unexpected if the source file is a binary file, and base64-encoding it will fix that problem.

If, however, the source file generating that error is already text, then you need to determine and specify what character set it is actually using. The 0x89 indicates it is neither ASCII nor UTF-8, so the most likely options are Latin-1 or Windows-1252.

Comment: My logic says this must be the answer and I had a feeling it was guessing ASCII incorrectly so I tried a couple of the encoding guessers for Ruby and the one I could get working told me the encoding was MACINTOSH. But I still got errors if I forced the encoding and encoded to utf-8.

Comment: Sorry, but this is WRONG. The file is pdf, so there should be NO conversion at all. THe file should be treated as binary file - unfortunately I do not know how to do it.

Comment: You can't embed a binary file into an XML document without first encoding it somehow.  And when you're manipulating a binary file as bytes, you can't use any String-manipulation stuff on it at all, because byte streams aren't Strings.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I have no idea why this is not upvoted more.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem (error) while trying to open and write a picture. It succeeded after adding "wb" as rights to the open method. Earlier, it was "w"

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had a similar issue and this was exactly what I had to do.

Comment: This is the answer. You need to change the type from `write` to `write binary`. Hence, `wb`.

Comment: It worked for me, trying to upload a CSV file (UTF-8). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could base 64 encode the string before embedding it into your xml:

```
require 'base64'
encoded_string = Base64.encode64(the_string)
```

Now `encoded_string` should be able to be embedded without problem. You'll need to decode it at the other end of course.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have control over the other end. But I will give this a go anyway.

Comment: @Kris bear in mind if you are embedding arbitrary binary files, they may contain things like `<` or `&` characters, or or control characters, null bytes and the like, so you're going to need to encode it somehow anyway. If the files are text you'll be ok working out the actual encoding and re-encoding them, but your list includes pdf and png files where you won't be able to that.