# ruby googlecharts issue

Tags: ruby, google-visualization, gchart

I am following instructions in this page

http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/

Here is my code

```
Gchart.line(:data => data,:axis_with_labels => ["x"],:axis_labels => ["0","15","30","45","60"], :format => 'file', :filename => "/path/to/file/#{stamp}.png")
```

I expect a chart with labels in x axis but I got this chart

[image]

Something I am missing in here?

**UPDATE**:

I fixed this issue with another extra pair of [] like this

```
Gchart.line(:data => data,:axis_with_labels => ["x"],:axis_labels => [["0","15","30","45","60"]], :format => 'file', :filename => "/path/to/file/#{stamp}.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

The example on the documentation has the same problem so it seems like a gem issue. I didn't feel like digging through the source but if you're not married to the gem, you can always try `gchart` which can be installed by `gem install gchart`.

Here is how you would do the same thing with `gchart`.

```
require 'gchart'

chart = GChart.line do |g| 
  g.data = data

  g.axis(:bottom) do |a| 
    a.labels = ["0", "15", "30", "45", "60"]
  end 

  g.axis(:bottom) do |a| 
    a.labels = ["x"]
    a.label_positions = [50]
  end 

  g.write("/path/to/file/#{stamp}.png")
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I install 'gem install gchart' and tried the code I got this error. "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 at g.write() line. Any idea?

Comment: Did you you pass any arguments to g.write? Can you put exactly what you pass in g.write?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177674/how-do-i-embed-an-uploaded-binary-files-ascii-8bit-in-an-xml-utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switching to the vertical bar delimited syntax. For example:

```
x_axis_labels = [1, 2, 3]
Gchart.line(:axis_labels => [x_axis_labels.join('|')], ...)
```

Probably a bug in the gem.